# UIPageViewController overlapping other view [Swift - UIStoryBoard]

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uistoryboard

I am trying add UIPageView with static position counter. But UIPageView page hiding Counter Label

Following code - I am creating PageViewController in my ControllerView.

```
func createPageViewController(){
    let pageVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: 
    Constant.storyIdPageViewIdentifier) as! UIPageViewController

    pageVC.dataSource = self

    if carsArray.count>0 {
        let imageController = getImageViewController(withIndex: 0)!

        let imageControllers = [imageController]
        pageVC.setViewControllers(imageControllers, direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    pageViewController = pageVC

    self.addChild(pageViewController!)
    self.view.addSubview(pageViewController!.view)
    pageViewController?.didMove(toParent: self)

}
```

[image: If i scroll right i can see counter]

[image: Pager view hiding counter label]

[image: Layout Hierarchy view.]

[image: 3d Debugging view]

Answer (score 2):

Try using   **self.view.bringSubviewToFront(counterlabel)**

Comment: its work but why its showing me two UIPageView.  can you tell me how we can use Containerview UIPageview controller in ControllerView

Comment: Can you please send me a screenshot so that i can interpretate

Comment: What is the name of your view that you want to put forward?